# How to use PERL XS to call a C++ function that takes in a STL Vector

Tags: c++, perl, xs

I have been using PerlXS to write a perl wrapper around a C++ Object. Usually my fcn takes in a string/int etc and I can just make them with no problem. I just write code like this in the .xs file

```
MyClass::func_a(std::string a, int b);
```

This time; I have a need to have a function that takes in a stl vector

```
MyClass::func_a(std::vector<std::string> vector)
```

I get this error:

```
conversion from `SV*' to non-scalar type 
  `std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't directly call the Native function which takes a STL container. You should write a wrapper and convert SV* manually to STL container.

If You don't know how to do this (like I was), try to use SWIG http://www.swig.org/

It can generate wrappers for a native funciton to use it from scripting languages (including PERL and XS-generator). The code from SWIG is not a very beautiful, also it has some limitations, but it is the easy way to write a wrapper.

SWIG has a limited support of STL builtin: http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Library.html#Library_stl_cpp_library

Also, for using PerlXS and vectors, check this thread http://www.mail-archive.com/perl-xs@perl.org/msg00623.html

Answer (score 2):

Check out XS++.

Some links:

[Slides for my talk at YAPC::EU on XS++](http://steffen-mueller.net/talks/xspp)

[The reference docs](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?ExtUtils%3a%3aXSpp)

[Instructions on how to use in a CPAN distribution](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Module%3a%3aBuild%3a%3aWithXSpp)

Comment: tsee, does XS++ automatically work with complex STL structures, like vector of strings

Comment: No. But there's a few reusable typemaps available on CPAN. See ExtUtils::Typemap and ExtUtils::Typemap::STL and its siblings. Specifically, vectors of strings are supported. What it doesn't do is automatic, recursive mapping. I.e. "I know how vectors work and how strings work. That means I also know how vectors of vectors of vectors of strings work."